# Access a file that was transferred from PC to Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I want to transfer a file to an Android device using a USB cable and file explorer, and then access it in my Xamarin.Forms app.

As far as I understand there are two ways to do this (and please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. Since it's an image file - Just put it anywhere and let some
   background task find it and add it to what seems to be a virtual
   folder of Images. And then access it there.
2. A more general solution - browse to that specific folder.

Both solutions rely on using `FileInfo`s etc. but unfortunately the folder structure is much different than I see using windows explorer - instead of `Alarms`, `Android`, etc. which I see on windows explorer - is see `cache`, `config`, etc. using C#, and access to some like `data` is not allowed (I get an exception). I also tried finding information on how I would search for all images on the device, but either it's not as simple as I thought it would be, or I'm using the wrong keywords.

The file will be put there by a user, so it cannot be added to the project's resources.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin has a nice way to navigate the files in android, using `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path`which you can concatenate with your directory/filename so you can save/access data.

If you want to open the android dialog box so the user can find a file in its device, you can take a look at: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/selecting_a_gallery_image/

Remembering that you need to add the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your android manifest file and check runtime permissions. Runtime permissions can be easily checked with https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin